# how to pull Multiple Months

Tags: sql-server, select

Here is what I have done so far. It only shows the month of April but I need months starting from Nov 15, 2015, to Mar 31, 2016

```
SELECT DATENAME(MM,GETDATE()) AS MONTH, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
  FROM S_SRV_REQ WITH (NOLOCK)          
  WHERE (dbo.fn_dstoffset(CREATED) >= '11-15-2015')
    AND (dbo.fn_dstoffset(CREATED) <= DATEADD(D, 1, '3-31-2016'))
    AND (INS_PRODUCT IN ('PS'))
    AND [SR_AREA] IS NOT NULL
    AND (SR_AREA IN ('Clinical Question'))
```

here is what I get

```
MONTH         TOTAL

April          28381
```

Comment: In order to gain assistance on StackOverflow, you'll need to be clearer on what your question is about. Currently it is a random collection of SQL and a result set, with very little else. The question is likely to be closed if people can't figure out what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to get the count in each month of date "CREATED"
First of all I am not sure you query is in MySQL OR MSSQL? 
1. In My SQL will change DATAADD to DATE_ADD 
2. In My SQL will MONTHNAME instead of DATENAME

In MSSQL will be something like:

```
SELECT DATENAME(month, dbo.fn_dstoffset(CREATED)) AS MONTH, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL 
FROM S_SRV_REQ WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE (dbo.fn_dstoffset(CREATED) >= '11-15-2015') 
    AND (dbo.fn_dstoffset(CREATED) <= DATEADD(D, 1, '3-31-2016')) 
    AND (INS_PRODUCT IN ('PS'))
    AND [SR_AREA] IS NOT NULL AND (SR_AREA IN ('Clinical Question'))
    GROUP BY DATENAME(month, dbo.fn_dstoffset(CREATED))
```

In MySQL will be something like:

```
    SELECT MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(month(dbo.fn_dstoffset(CREATED)), '%m')) AS MONTH, 
COUNT(*) AS TOTAL 
    FROM S_SRV_REQ WITH (NOLOCK)
        WHERE (dbo.fn_dstoffset(CREATED) >= '11-15-2015') 
        AND (dbo.fn_dstoffset(CREATED) <= DATE_ADD('3-31-2016',INTERVAL 1 DAY)
        AND (INS_PRODUCT IN ('PS')) 
        AND [SR_AREA] IS NOT NULL AND (SR_AREA IN ('Clinical Question'))
        GROUP BY MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(month(dbo.fn_dstoffset(CREATED)), '%m'))
```